# How to prevent reflection attack in Needham-Schroeder in ECB mode?

Tags: protocol-design, protocol-analysis, needham-schroeder

We know that Needham-Schroeder is vulnerable to a reflection attack as shown [here](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse484/11au/lectures/Lecture24-Au-2011.pdf).
How can I make it secure using ECB and without using timestamps? I need to modify the protocol. Otwan-Rees is a possible solution. Is there any other way which doesn't deviate much from the original protocol.